# R code for OR statement between treatment and control group

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm running a logit regression to analyze grade completion during a given period. I'm trying to use the Pre period as my control group and the Post period as my treatment group. I want an "or" statement to compare the treatment with the control group. Basically I want R to run my `glm` if `Pre==1` OR `Post==1`. All these variables are dummies.

I keep getting the error message:

> "the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used."

What I'm understanding is that it's not taking both conditions into account.I have already tried the following:

```
Grd7<-glm(Grade7~Intensity*Post,if((Pre|Post==1)),family="binomial")
if((Pre==1)|(Post==1))
if(1 %in% c(Pre,Post))
if(any(Pre==1)|any(Post==1))
```

I expect the results to be different when including the if statement in comparison to without it. However, I keep getting the same result in both cases.

Comment: use `if (any(Pre==1, Post==1))`

Comment: Presumably each row is either `pre` or `post`, no row is both, no row is neither. In this case, typically you would leave `pre` out of the model, letting the intercept term account for the `pre` condition, then the `post` variable will be the difference between pre and post. Your formula can be simply `Grade7 ~ Intensity * Post`.

Comment: @RAB it gave me the same result as the original regression, without the IF statement. However, the error message did not appear this time

Comment: @Gregor The issue with doing that is I have several other in-between periods as well. So excluding the IF statement would make the control group everything besides Post.

Comment: I think we might need some example data to show us what you mean and what you're trying to get.

Comment: Well then it sounds like you need to include both, without the `if`. R will take care of the model matrix for you if you have a single factor column with `pre`, `post`, and any intermediate states as well. Hard to help more specifically than that without data. Or, if you want to run the regression on a subset of your data, then subset the data. Use the `subset` argument, `subset = Pre == 1 | Post == 1` (assuming your data is `attach`ed--which it looks like it is, though most people recommend against it)